# Helper class for performance tests using StopWatch class

Tags: c#, .net, stopwatch

In this example code i am using a simple StopWatch to test time that it takes to complete a given task/action

```
StopWatch SW1 = new StopWatch();
SW1.Start();
SomeAction();
SW1.Stop();
sting results = SW1.Elapsed.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(resutls);
```

i would like to have a class that i will instantiate to use with tests

```
public Class PerformanceTests
{
   public StopWatch SW1 = new StopWatch();
   public StopWatch SW2 = new StopWatch();
   public string results1 = "", results2 = "";
   ....
   ....
   //some other variables to use 
}
```

though when instantiating the class and trying to use `SW1` is not letting me use its methods. What am i doing wrong ?

```
PerformanceTests Ptst = new PerformanceTests();
Ptst.SW1. ... Start() is not accessible
```

**Update**

For rest of answers, don't copy the code from me, as I miss capitalized `stopwatch`. Instead of instantiating the Stopwatch class i accidentally didn't pay attention Visual Studio asking if i want to create a class for my so called stopwatch instead of .NET's real `Stopwatch`.

So my advice, pay attention to the suggested actions of Visual Studio intellisense 
even though it should be same all the time . Just make sure till you're really experienced and know all the classes by heart.

Comment: `intelliSense` sounds like an Apple product. Edited that, and many

Comment: I wrote an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969290/exact-time-measurement-for-performance-testing/16157458#16157458

Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232848/wrapping-stopwatch-timing-with-a-delegate-or-lambda

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is simple class, which can help you for measuring time of code block execution:

```
public class PerformanceTester : IDisposable
{
    private Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    private Action<TimeSpan> _callback;

    public PerformanceTester()
    {
        _stopwatch.Start();
    }

    public PerformanceTester(Action<TimeSpan> callback) : this()
    {
        _callback = callback;            
    }

    public static PerformanceTester Start(Action<TimeSpan> callback)
    {
        return new PerformanceTester(callback);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _stopwatch.Stop();
        if (_callback != null)
            _callback(Result);
    }

    public TimeSpan Result
    {
        get { return _stopwatch.Elapsed; }
    }
}
```

Usage (just wrap code block with using of `PerformanceTester`):

```
using (var tester = new PerformanceTester())
{
    // code to test
    MessageBox.Show(tester.Results.ToString());
}
```

If you declare tester variable before `using` block, then stopwatch will stop automatically when you exit `using` block, and results will be available for you:

```
PerformanceTester tester;

using (tester = new PerformanceTester())    
    SomeAction();

MessageBox.Show(tester.Results.ToString());
```

If you pass callback action to `PerformanceTester`, then this action will be called at the end of `using` statement, and elapsed time will be passed to callback:

```
using (PerformanceTester.Start(ts => MessageBox.Show(ts.ToString())))
     SomeAction();
```

You can declare method, which will accept `TimeSpan` and process results:

```
private void ProcessResult(TimeSpan span)
{
   // log, show, etc
   MessageBox.Show(span.ToString());
}
```

Usage becomes very clean:

```
using (PerformanceTester.Start(ProcessResult))
     SomeAction();
```

Comment: it was strangley made while i was taking the intelliSence Suggestion instead of using statment i was creating a class , becuse i missSpelled (capitalisation) *i think it should BE! `StopWatch()` !! (:
thanks. cause without this mistake , i wouldn't have chance to see your neat ext' method ! +1 for cool class

Comment: by the way it is also letting you avoid the use of un necessary imports of other classes of dot.net in the application webform/winform . does it help in any way i mean is the fact that i try to have as less as i can `using` statements, means less class imports , does it have any effect , or while i instanciate the class i am then using the .net class (System.diagnostics) so it does not matter atleast in the aspect of resulting size of aplication .

Comment: how to declare tester out of the using (before) can u give another example as in your comment below your answer "if you declare tester variable before using `block`..." can you   broad a little

Comment: @LoneXcoder Sorry, was AFK, I've added sample with declaring tester before using block

Comment: ..tested your class, very nice one , thanks , i used a declared string before the usage and assigned it the `Results.ToString();` then after using block, i've accessed the string i have declared before the using statement

Comment: @LoneXcoder I've added another, more handy version of performance tester. Take a look on it :)

Comment: this looks more advanced version of your initial one though this time it uses a task start. gonna run some tests on those, Cheers, thanks for your time , i am doing lot's of investigations latlely, about new technologies (for me) you can have a look on my latests post regarding partial data (segmets) downloading to increase downlod speed (it's rewarding 100 points(: for right answer) so feel free to take part!

Answer (score 1):

make them public instead of private:

```
 public class PerformanceTests
    {
        public StopWatch SW1 { get; set; }

        public StopWatch SW2 { get; set; }

        public string Results1 { get; set; }

        public string Results2 { get; set; }

        public PerformanceTests()
        {
            this.SW1 = new StopWatch();
            this.SW2 = new StopWatch();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a custom class StopWatch is not the correct class name try [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) under the namespace `System.Diagnostics`

Try:

```
public Class PerformanceTests
{
   public Stopwatch SW1 = new Stopwatch();
   public Stopwatch SW2 = new Stopwatch();
   public string results1 = "", results2 = "";
   ....
   ....
   //some other variables to use 
}
```